# How to use a sheet as a function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an input cell B1 for Package from which monthly in-hand is calculated in cell E22. I have to calculate the monthly in-hand for lot of packages. It is time taking process to put each package once in the cell B1 and copy the calculated monthly in-hand from cell E22.

Is there an easier way to fill the cells H3 to H12?

Something like:

H3 = Value of E22 when B1 = G3
H4 = Value of E22 when B1 = G4
H5 = Value of E22 when B1 = G5

[image]

Comment: you can just check the "If" Formula. 
I=If(B1=G4;E22;"")

Comment: Simple IF: `=IF(G3=$B$1,$E$22,"")`

Comment: Could be a case for using a Data Table.  On the Data tab on the Ribbon there should be a What-if analysis drop down that has a Data Table expand then follow your nose.

Comment: Inserted spaces to make question clearer

Comment: Thanks Mark Fitzgerald. It works like a charm.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald If you could post your comment as an Answer rather than a Comment, I could mark this question as Answered.

Comment: When I find the time to reproduce your sheet so I can show pictures of the Data Table setup I'll post an answer.  Maybe tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Just to mark it as answered I am posting this. Actual answer is in Mark Fitzgerald's comment above. Thanks Mark.